# How can you use mathematical notation of a logarithm to distinguish between the possible results?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

What I've just asked might appear ambiguous and I suppose I could clarify myself with an example: e to the 0 is 1 as it should be, but e to the 2π*i* is 1 at the same time, so the base e logarithm of 1 is 0 and 2π*i* simultaneously. What I'm asking is if there's a method in which we can indicate a specific power to pick as an output from a logarithm operation. For instance, if we use ln(1) in an operation, I'm asking for the method in which we can use ln(1) as 2π*i* by indicating that it should be that number (instead of the default 0).

I have an idea about this, but it's not based on anything official. Basically, I thought that you should be able to indicate logarithms as ln(*x*): t=*y* where *x* is preferably a complex number, and *y* is the total number of 2π radian turns around the complex plane. For instance, if I say ln($\sqrt{2}$+$\sqrt{2}$*i*): t=0, its equivalent is π/4 and if I say ln($\sqrt{2}$+$\sqrt{2}$*i*): t=1, its equivalent is 9π/4 and so on. So what I'm doing here is basically ln(*x*)+*y*·2π but without using the irrational numbers.

Comment: There is a way, and it is known as taking a branch cut. This is a really deep concept, so do not expect to get a full comprehensive answer here; many people might just tell you to go look it up.

Comment: Look for "Riemann surface". For $\log$ it is especially simple.

Comment: @Valborg:your comment is stupendously useless.  Who are you to decide what is deep and what is not and whether this question will get a useful answer on MSE?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you on the comment being useless. I gave the name of the concept that the poster wanted to know, but also stated that it is a concept that is deep, which is without a doubt true, since most people don't see branch cuts until they are in graduate school. And given that it is a concept that is considered advanced, I think it is a safe assumption that most people won't bother writing the several pages that are necessary to introduce the concept in complete rigor. I'm not deciding what is deep or if this will get an answer, I'm framing the nature of the question.

Comment: I think that your suggested expression, in terms of minimum complete revolutions, is neat. 

It would be equivalent to talk of (for example) least $\theta$ such that $\ln x = (2k\pi+\theta)i$, $x\in \mathbb C$, $k$ a specified integer. (The only thing that this would have over your idea is that it wouldn't involve introducing a new expression form.)